# How to add different audio for every container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Something like this: http://porschevolution.com/

I have this code for every container that is 100% height:

```
 <audio controls autoplay>
        <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Do I need now some JS code so every container starts his own song?

Thx, if this is not easy thing to do, can you share some tutorial with me?

Comment: check js files view-source:http://porschevolution.com/js/js.js

Comment: http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/  http://www.unheap.com/media/audio-video/

Comment: Okay, thx for the links.